Adding custom set method of a property in Kotlin interfaces without referencing a backing field?
I try to implement a custom set method for a property in an interface. How does one do it without referencing a backing field?
interface EmailUser {
  val email: String
  var jina: String
  val nickname: String
    get() = email.substringAfter('@')
  var names: String
    set(value: String) {
        jina = value + "@"}
    }


You are not referencing a backing field in your code. You just need to declare a getter for names. What do you want the getter to return?

Thank you for the response. I would like it to return 'jina'. But what I really want to know is if property setters are possible in interfaces

Okay, so just add get() = jina then. It is possible as long as you also declare a getter.

Thank you so much! It works and I have learnt something new.

A property with only a setter is considered to have a backing field. If you also implement a default implementation for the getter, there will be no backing field and the code will compile.
In this case, an implementation like this could be suitable:
var names: String
    get() = jina.trimEnd('@')
    set(value) {
        jina = value + "@"
    }

